# "linked by land and sea" VS "linked by the land and sea"

Tags: definite-article

> 1. As a close and intimate neighbor **linked by land and sea**, China and ASEAN launched the dialogue process in 1991 and forged a strategic partnership in 2003.
> 2. As a close and intimate neighbor **linked by the land and sea**, China and ASEAN launched the dialogue process in 1991 and forged/entered into/formed a strategic partnership in 2003.

Do we need the definite artice herein?

Comment: I think **neighbors** would be better there than *a neighbor*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need an article there.

When the noun refers in context to a **mode** (to *how* something is done or to *how* it is accomplished or effected or to *how* it exists) the article is not needed.

> They arrived by train.
>
> They are linked by land and (by) sea.
>
> Fishing in these waters is governed by treaty.